# What do I need to do to get WebGL up and running on my Mac?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, webgl

I've got a 2007 MacPro, 8GB RAM, 2 x NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT (256 MB). I tried to look at a couple of Google's [WebGL demos](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl), for example [this one](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/webgl-cadillac-ranch/?f=webgl) but am unable to do so because 
my system is not WebGL compatible.

I'm running Lion and the latest version of Chrome - what else do I need to do? Or is my 'bleeding-edge' workstation now a relic of the past?

Comment: ide say its a relic of the past, joking

Comment: Safari installed on Mac OS X Lion has support for WebGL, which is disabled by default http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a compatible browser, and half-way decent hardware. (Which you have)

See http://get.webgl.org for better instructions.

**[EDIT!]**

Actually, after looking through get.webgl.org a bit more, they explicitly state that your card is incompatible:

> If you have the following graphics cards, WebGL is unsupported and is disabled by default:
>
> Mac:
>
> - ATI Radeon HD2400
> - ATI Radeon 2600 series
> - ATI Radeon X1900
> - **GeForce 7300 GT**

This is probably because of driver bugs that they've found affect the stability of the browser. (Most vendors have lousy OpenGL support, even on systems like the Mac!)

You still may be able to force WebGL to enable through by navigating to `about:flags` in Chrome and seeing if it has an `Enable WegGL` option.